# How to get path of view file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, view, path

I wanted to ask if there is any way i can get path of my view file in controller. For example

```
class welcome extends controller{

  function __construct(){
       parent::__construct();
  }
  function index(){
     $this->load->view('welcome_message');
  }
  function test(){
     $my_variable = $this->load->view('welcome_message','',TRUE);
  }
  function another_test(){
        ///  $path_to_view = ???;
        ///  echo $path_to_view;
  } 
}
```

i want to ask if there is any helper function to get this. The test method has variable containing the html contents in it. But i want to get path of view file???

Comment: What do you *really* want to do?

Comment: i am trying to use this class which requires path of view file.This converts html into pdf. i know there are many other converter classes but i wes only curious to know how to get path of view file http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3168-PHP-Generate-PDF-documents-from-HTML-pages.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a proper way but you can try this, just create a helper file i.e. `my_helper.php` in your `application/helper` folder and paste following function in this helper file

```
function get_view_path($view_name)
{
    $target_file=APPPATH.'views/'.$view_name.'.php';
    if(file_exists($target_file)) return $target_file;
}
```

To use it you have to load the helper file first and then call the function with the name of the view as the function's argument

```
$this->load->helper('my_helper');
$path_to_view = get_view_path('welcome'); // Will return the path if welcome.php exists in the view folder.
```

You can auto load it using config.php's `$autoload['helper'] = array('functions_helper');`

Comment: Please let me know if you get something better than this.

Comment: well i can create a function now in uri class then i will be able to use it like this $this->uri->get_path('my_view',$type); where $type = 'view' others can be model , controller. I like using class way of calling functions instead of straight function calls

Answer (score 7):

It should be the constant:

```
VIEWPATH
```